# Change key string in Firebase objective c

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update the key of a node in Firebase

```
gameList - root node
Basketball - child node of gameList
   addedBy: "xxx" - child node of key Basketball
   gamename: "Basketball" - child node of key Basketball
```

My data is like this.  Now I can update child node's value gamename (Basketball).  But I can't able to update the key BasketBall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have the concept of "renaming" a part of the path via update. Instead you will have to completely remove the existing node and recreate it.

You can do that like so:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database();
dbRef.child(gameList).once('value').then(function(snap) {
  var data = snap.val();
  data.gamename = newgamename;
  var update = {};
  update[gamename] = null;
  update[newgamename] = data;
  return dbRef.update(update);
});
```

This will remove the info from `gameList/gamename` and re-populate it with a new name in `gameList/newgamename`.

**Important Note:**
If one person is likely to edit the data at a time, the above solution is fine. If not, you may want to consider using a non-user-controlled identifier such as a push id.